# From VS 2k3 to VS 2k8 - MFC Application not rendering properly in Release config

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

**EDIT** Problem solved, see below

---

We had to migrate a MFC application from Visual Studio 2003 to 2008 a while back. It went OK for the most part, except for a huge flaw : the release build doesn't display our dialogs right, whereas the debug build works just fine.

Here is a sample of what it should look like (and what it looks like in debug) :
http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/864144InterfaceOK1OUT.png

(The black squares are on the picture on purpose)
And here is what the release build looks like :
http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/813251InterfaceKO1OUT.png

Now, to try to solve this, I went through different steps :

- I built the runtime library with **/MDd** in Release configuration, and ran it out of VS (dirty, I know); it works (well, I get an error when closing, which could be expected), but it's obviously far from ideal.
- I ran Dependency Walker on Debug and Release executables and compared them both : apart from the Debug DLL (MSVC[PR]90D and MFC90D), it's mostly the same. I didn't find anything meaningful there.
- I tried to debug my Release build by following the steps described in MSDN msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsk896zz(v=vs.90).aspx , which presented a peculiar behaviour : while debugging the exe in VS, the dialogs were rendered correctly. However, taking the same .exe file and launching out of VS presented the wrong dialogs display again.

I thought at first that it was some DLL that wasn't here or was in the wrong version (oh, it's probably relevant to mention that we also went from x86 to x64 systems; the application is still developed in 32 bits though), but since the Release debugging, I'm not so sure, since it doesn't use the Debug DLLs (verified it in process explorer).

I'm at a loss here and furthermore not really c++ savvy, so any help at all would be greatly appreciated :)

**EDIT** Both dialogs contain actually the same components, the one in the Release build appears "collapsed", mostly in the upper left corner, as if it didn't know where to put the components.

**EDIT** OK, problem solved :

OK, that was quite silly...

The problem was in the following bit of code :

```
CMainFrame* pFrame = new CMainFrame;
m_pMainWnd = pFrame;
CRect rect;
pFrame->Create(NULL, formatString(IDR_TITRE), WS_CAPTION | MFS_SYNCACTIVE, rect, 0);
```

("CMainFrame" inherits from CMiniFrameWnd)

"CRect rect;" was OK in VS2003, and even appears to be OK in Debug build in VS 2008, although in retrospect I assume it was wrong all along since it doesn't initialize the object (as said here : msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/9y3502k0(v=vs.90).aspx ). So for some reason, this wouldn't work in the Release build.

I had to edit it like so :

```
CMainFrame* pFrame = new CMainFrame;
m_pMainWnd = pFrame;
CRect rect(0,0,0,0);
pFrame->Create(NULL, formatString(IDR_TITRE), WS_CAPTION | MFS_SYNCACTIVE, rect, 0);
```

The dimensions of the frame are reworked later, so it doesn't really matter which value I assign to it, but it appears I have to assign them.

With this done, the application works and appears fine.

Thanks Michael for pointing me in the right direction, I was going for a more far fetched solution.

Comment: It looks as if it is a different dialog. In the 2nd one you "Afficher une boîte de dilaogue pour le bac manuel" but in the 1st one you have "Imprimante par défaut". Did you try a "rebuild all" ?

Comment: It's actually the same dialog, everything is simply "collapsed" in the 2nd screenshot; the ticking box shown in the 2nd is simply one of the blackened one in the first (I forgot to put a black box there in the 2nd, it might be confusing, my mistake).

Comment: Don't put black boxes when there is no sensible information. Try to find out when the dialog gets collapsed by calling GetWindowRect in different places in your OnInitDialog function.

Comment: There's no simple explanation for such drastic layout differences.  Nobody can debug your code from a screenshot.

Comment: @MichaelWalz : Yeah, i admit i went a bit overkill with the boxes, sorry. I will try logging various GetWindowRect and see how it goes. Hans : I know the description's a bit vague, but I'm looking for any pointers to narrow down the solution. I'll update with the information I get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of [CFrameWnd::Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y17z36a%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) clearly states that you must provide a rectangle containing the desired size and position of the window or your must provide the default rectangle (rectDefault) which lets Windows choose the size and position.

This default rectangle is defined like this in MFC :

```
const AFX_DATADEF CRect CFrameWnd::rectDefault( CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 0);
```

CW_USEDEFAULT is defined like this in WinUser.h:

```
#define CW_USEDEFAULT       ((int)0x80000000)
```

Now I suppose that you probably just were lucky and your application might have failed depending on the uninitialized value of the rectangle even with VS2K3.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. What I get is that the uninitialized value wasn't the same in debug as the one in release (and the same goes for VS2K3, as you say). Glad that's done with.